# how excatly to use PurifyCSS Online tool with blogger?

Tags: css, blogger, purifycss

PurifyCSS Online removes unused CSS. I have an URL in my template (http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/droidarabickufi.css). After PurifyCSS removed unused CSS it gave me the following code:

```
en@font-face{font-family:'Droid Arabic Kufi';font-style:normal;font-weight:400;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.eot);src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.woff) format('woff'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Regular.ttf) format('truetype')}@font-face{font-family:'Droid Arabic Kufi';font-style:normal;font-weight:700;src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.eot);src:url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.eot?#iefix) format('embedded-opentype'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.woff2) format('woff2'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.woff) format('woff'),url(//fonts.gstatic.com/ea/droidarabickufi/v6/DroidKufi-Bold.ttf) format('truetype')}
```

How will I replace this code with the URL in my template?